# Accessing 3-dimensional matrix by a 2-dimensional index in matlab/octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a 3 dimensional matrix (3rd dimension represents multiple copies of an `M x N` grayscale image).

I'm taking the max value of each pixel across the images, giving me a `max_val` and `max_ix` matrix (2x2).

I want to reference the original `test` matrix by the `max_ix` values.

Example: `my_max_val = test(max_ix,:)` should equal:

```
     5     1
     1     1
```

Obviously I can just use `max_val` in this simplified example, but not in the real use case. I'm altering `max_ix`, so I need to reference the original 3-dimensional matrix by the new index values I create (not depicted in this simplified example).

```
>> test

test(:,:,1) =

     1     1
     1     1


test(:,:,2) =

     1     1
     1     1


test(:,:,3) =

     5     1
     1     1


test(:,:,4) =

     1     1
     1     1

>> [max_val, max_ix] = max(test, [], 3)

max_val =

     5     1
     1     1


max_ix =

     3     1
     1     1
```

How do I recreate `max_val` just from `test` and `max_ix`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach -

```
%// Get size of 3D input array
[m,n,~] = size(test);     

%// Calculate 2D starting, offset & finally actual indices array
start_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[1:m]',[0:n-1]*m);  %//'
offset_idx = m*n*(max_ix-1);
actual_idx = start_idx + offset_idx;

%// Index into 3D input array to extract specific elements, for desired output
max_val = test(actual_idx)
```

Thus, essentially giving us a two-liner solution, if you are into *compact* codes -

```
[m,n,~] = size(test);     
max_val = test( bsxfun(@plus,[1:m]',[0:n-1]*m) + m*n*(max_ix-1) )
```

Please note that `bsxfun(@plus,[1:m]',[0:n-1]*m)` could be replaced by `reshape(1:m*n,m,n)`.

**Sample run**

Inputs:

```
test(:,:,1) =
    12    66    75    98
    65    75    24    87
    33    59    74     9
test(:,:,2) =
    37    60    21    21
    37    79     9    39
    69    37    78    56
test(:,:,3) =
    23    16    30    10
    65    79    24    41
    49    11    54    11
test(:,:,4) =
    12    61    70    66
    79    97    76    11
    30    44    44    94
max_ix =
     1     2     2     2
     2     4     1     2
     4     2     3     3
```

Output:

```
max_val =
    12    60    21    21
    37    97    24    39
    30    37    54    11
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution (and a clean one!), I thought this was just going to be an issue of me not knowing some syntax, I didn't realize I'd need to do this many steps to achieve it. Thanks for taking the time to do this (and run all the tests, I was watching the edits as they kept coming in). :)

Comment: @DavidParks Awesome! Now you know how "clean" solutions evolve :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
%// Generate matrix test
test = randi(50,4,4,4);

%// Get maximum value and indices
[max_val, max_ix] = max(test, [], 3);

%// We don't know the size in general so this is the Cartesian product
[y, x] = meshgrid(1:size(test, 1), 1:size(test,2));

%// sub2ind provide the single value indices for a matrix of size(test) 
%// at positions [x(:), y(:), max_ix(:)] and reshape brings it back to the correct shape
max_val2 = reshape(test(sub2ind(size(test), x(:) , y(:), max_ix(:))), size(x));
```

Comment: This one's getting me a different result than the max_val generated by max in a quick test I did, I'm looking for the problem, but might just go with another answer here. Using meshgrid was an interesting approach though, it taught me some useful tricks, thank you for that!